# Fragment erro "Unable to start activity"

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragment, android-activity

Minha aplicação da erro ao abrir em um tablet e não consigo identificar o erro ele informa que tenho que habilitar:

> Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.everton.horoscopo/com.example.everton.horoscopo.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML
>   file line #15: Error inflating class fragment.

Não entendi o erro segue os código se alguém pode me ajudar agradeço.
Minha main activity

```
package com.example.everton.horoscopo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.everton.horoscopo.fragments.HoroscopoDetailFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnHoroscopoClickLlistener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }



    private boolean istablet() {
        return getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.tablet);

    }

    private boolean isSmartphone() {
        return getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.smartphone);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMovieClick (long id){
        if (isSmartphone()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "bbb " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HoroscopoDetailActivity.class);
            it.putExtra("Horosc", String.valueOf(id));
            startActivity(it);

        } else {
            HoroscopoDetailFragment horoscopoDetailFragment = new HoroscopoDetailFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frag_detalhe, horoscopoDetailFragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

o xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.everton.horoscopo.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="390dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.example.everton.horoscopo.fragments.HoroscopoListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentLista"/>

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.example.everton.horoscopo.fragments.HoroscopoDetailFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentDetail"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

e o erro

```
10-09 16:50:34.702 23809-23815/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
10-09 16:50:35.111 23809-23809/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.everton.horoscopo, PID: 23809 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.everton.horoscopo/com.example.everton.horoscopo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
   at com.example.everton.horoscopo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
   at com.example.everton.horoscopo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
   at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
   at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
   at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
   at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:137)
   at com.example.everton.horoscopo.fragments.HoroscopoDetailFragment.onCreateView(HoroscopoDetailFragment.java:50)
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1332)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2288)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:356)
   at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
   at com.example.everton.horoscopo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 2):

Pessoal desculpa a demora pra responder é que estava sem tempo para ve. Resolvi o problema. O problema era que no main activity não estava passando o Bundle para a classe do detail fragment segue a solução:

Main activity

```
 frag = findViewById(R.id.fragmentDetail);
           HoroscopoDetailFragment horoscopoDetailFragment= HoroscopoDetailFragment.newInstance(id);
            horoscopoDetailFragment.teste(true);
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragmentDetail, horoscopoDetailFragment)
                    .show(horoscopoDetailFragment)
                    .commit();
```

inicialmente passei o Bundle pela main mas depois criei um metodo e passei por la.

DetailFragment

```
 public static HoroscopoDetailFragment newInstance(long id) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("Horosc", String.valueOf(id));
    HoroscopoDetailFragment horoscopoDetailFragment= new HoroscopoDetailFragment();
    horoscopoDetailFragment.setArguments(args);
    return horoscopoDetailFragment;
}
```

Obrigado a todos pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

No seu `.xml` consta desta forma `R.id.fragmentDetail` e na sua classe você chama `R.id.frag_detalhe`. Tente conferir e colocar corretamente os identificadores pois estão com *ids* diferentes.

Outro possível erro está no .xml no qual você define o nome do seu fragment.

```
android:name="com.example.everton.horoscopo.fragments.HoroscopoListFragment"
```

Tente alterar para class.

```
class="com.example.everton.horoscopo.fragments.HoroscopoListFragment"
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, Everton

Vamos observar o trecho abaixo onde você infla o fragment em sua activity:

```
HoroscopoDetailFragment horoscopoDetailFragment = new HoroscopoDetailFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frag_detalhe, horoscopoDetailFragment)
                    .commit();
```

Esse treco indica que você está relacionando uma instância de `HoroscopoDetailFragment` no componente visual que tenha o id `frag_detalhe`, certo? Vamos agora observa o seu layout para vermos onde se encontrar esse componente visual com esse id:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.everton.horoscopo.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="390dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.example.everton.horoscopo.fragments.HoroscopoListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentLista"/>

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.example.everton.horoscopo.fragments.HoroscopoDetailFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentDetail"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Consigo ver dois componentes `fragment`, um com o id `fragmentLista` e outro com o id `fragmentDetail`, mas não consigo ver alguém com o id `frag_detalhe`. O que está acontecendo é que o código está tentando inflar um componente visual com um id que não existe.

O que você precisa fazer é apenas ajustar os ids, ou modificando no layout ou modificando na Activity, para que os dois referenciem o mesmo componente com os mesmo id.

Abraço